# Tenho um menu fixo, como fazer ancoragem (#links internos) ficarem abaixo do menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

Estou trabalhando em um site que possui uma navbar e um menu **(a altura dos dois somadas dá 101px)**, que ao rolar até eles, eles fixam no topo da tela e ficam flutuantes.

Estou querendo que as âncoras que defini na página não sejam sobrepostas pelo menu quando clicadas pelo usuário nos botões do menu.

Por exemplo, quando o usuário clica em "Principais Datas" a âncora leva até o local desejado, mas como o menu flutua ele fica por cima do título. Dá pra resolver mudando a posição do  na página, mas isso também modifica a altura da página.

Vi alguns modelos de resolução utilizando JQuery, mas todos que testei não funcionaram.

Meu site: https://sienpro.catalao.ufg.br/

O que quero fazer é como esse exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/yjcRv/346/

Estou usando esse código:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e) {

    var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
    var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - 101;

    $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 600, function(target){
        window.location.hash = target;
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});

</script>
```

Ah e os links do menu não estão definidos simplesmente como "#link", estão completos https://sienpro.catalao.ufg.br/#link, pois se o usuário estiver em outra página ele será redirecionado para página correta e a âncora irá levá-lo para posição definida.

Comment: Cara tem uma forma de fazer só com CSS e HTML, mas é meio que uma "gambiarra". Vc vai ter que fazer uma "Ancora Oculta" que vai evitar que o título fica encoberto pelo menu dando um espaço para o topo da página. Se quiser eu posto na resposta.

Comment: Se puder! Eu acho que seria uma das maneiras mais fáceis de resolver! Só quero que fique funcional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percebi alguns problemas no código:

**1º.** Ao usar o `animate` do jQuery com âncoras, não use `name="alvo"`; use `id="alvo"`. Portanto altere tudo que tiver `name="alvo"` para `id="alvo"` (ex., `name="datas"` para `id="datas"`). Mude também a tag de `<a>` para `<div>`, ficando `<div id="alvo"></div>`.

**2º.** Esta forma de capturar o click:

```
$('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e) {
```

Além de faltar aspas no `#`, procure não usar `.bind`, porque já foi descontinuado a partir da versão 3 do jQuery. Em vez disso, use `.on()`.

Outra coisa, parece que esses `<a>` referenciados são dinâmicos e o jQuery não está conseguindo identificá-los. Para resolver isso, altere a forma de captura para:

```
$(document).on("click", 'a[href*="#"]', function(e) {
```

**3º.** Este código:

```
var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - 101;
```

Percebi que `101` não é o valor correto. Use algo em torno de `200` porque precisa compensar aquele topo acima do menu. Então ficaria:

```
var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - 200;
```

Então o código ficaria assim:

```
$(document).on("click", 'a[href*="#"]', function(e) {

    var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
    var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - 200;

    $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 600, function(){
       window.location.hash = target;
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Lucas com falei no comentário e vc pediu o exemplo vou explicar como que com CSS e HTML vc consegue resolver isso. Tudo bem que essa não é uma forma muito "elegante", mas pode resolver no seu caso.

A técnica concite em criar um elemento de 1px e cor transparente que vai funcionar como uma ***ancora oculta***, com o `position:absolut` vc vai tirar esse elemento do fluxo da página e ele não vai interferir nos outros elementos.

Segue um exemplo prático para vc entender melhor

**OBS:** *Eu deixei os comentário no código para facilitar*

```css
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
} 
body {
    min-height: 2000px;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
div#header{
   position: fixed;
   top:0px;
   width:100%;
   height:80px;
   background: red;
   z-index: 999;
}

div#target{
   font-size:40px;
   border-top:1px solid red; 
   height: 80px;
}

/* Ancora Oculta - Classe do elemento que vai ser  */
#ancora1, #ancora2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -100px; /* esse valor varia de acordo com a altura do seu Header, se ele tiver 200px de altura coloque aqui -220px por exemplo */
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <a href="#ancora1"># Ancora 1 #</a>
    <a href="#ancora2"># Ancora 2 #</a>
</div>

<div id="target" style="position: relative;">content!</div>
<div id="target">content!</div>
<div id="target" style="position: relative;">content!</div>
<div id="target">content!</div>
<!-- Elemento com o ID para fazer a Ancora 1 -->
<div id="ancora1"></div> 
<div id="target"># Ancora 1 #</div>
<div id="target">content!</div>
<div id="target">content!</div>
<!-- Elemento com o ID para fazer a Ancora 1 -->
<div id="ancora2"></div>
<div id="target"># Ancora 2 #</div>
```

Como eu disse não é uma técnica muito elegante, mas pode te ajudar sem precisar de JavaScript

Comment: #ancora1, #ancora2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -100px; /* esse valor varia de acordo com a altura do seu Header, se ele tiver 200px de altura coloque aqui -220px por exemplo */
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
} 

Essa parte resolveu, obrigado!

Comment: Lucas mas é essa parte ai mesmo que é o **ouro** rss. Ela que faz a mágica. Não é muito elegante, mas resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Caso o elemento .menu-bar e .menu_component estejam com a classe "fixar" basta você subtrair o tamanho deles(que você disse ser 101px).

```
$('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': (scrollToPosition - (101 + 33)) }, 600, function(target){
    window.location.hash = target;
})
```

Agora se eles não estiverem com a classe "fixar" então além de subtrair o 10 do tamanho do menu você tem que tirar tbm o tamanho do elemento cabecalho(100) e do elemento first_place(33)

```
$('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': (scrollToPosition - (101 + 33 + 100 )) }, 600, function(target){
    window.location.hash = target;
})
```

Em um resumo da opera, você tem que calcular com o tamanho do elemento cabecalho e first_place

Answer (score 0):

"Joguei" esse mesmo código no *codepen* trocando o `bind` por `on` e o seletor para `('#header > a')` e funcionou:

Edit: aqui tinha o link para uma solução no codepen, porém fui advertido de não poder postar links externos.

conteudo do link:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    Header: <a href="#target">Click me!</a>
</div>

   <div id="target">My target content!</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#header > a').on("click", function(e) {

var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - 80;

$('html').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 600, function(target){
        window.location.hash = target;
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Coloque o seu código na resposta. Evite links externos

Comment: Funciona, mas eu quero que funcione também quando o usuário acessar o link de outra página. Então quero desabilitar o "jump" automático pra hashtag, carregar a página e depois deslizar até a hashtag. Tentei fazer como esse link mas não consegui entender. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096621/how-to-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page/29823834#29823834

Comment: Na verdade você pode adicionar o link, porém o ideal é adicionar um trecho relevante do link, pois o endereço da página pode expirar e a resposta se tornar "inválida".

Comment: Por exemplo quando vc acessa o link direto https://sienpro.catalao.ufg.br/#contato, ele já pula direto para onde está a ancoragem, sem passar pelo Javascript e aí o menu continua na frente do título. Mas se clicar em um botão que está href="#contato" ele realiza o scroll corretamente.